# How set is working for duplicates entry and remove operations in java

Tags: java, set

I have written following code

```
class Test {

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{   

    Set<Integer> s = new HashSet();
    Integer i1 = new Integer(1);
    s.add(i1);
    Integer i2 = new Integer(2);
    s.add(i2);
    i1 = 5;
    s.remove(i1);
    System.out.println("size= "+s.size());
  }
}
```

**Output: 2**

I have added two integers(`i1` and `i2`) in `set` and `i1` is modified.
When `s.remove(i1)` is there, output is 2

when I comment out `s.remove(i1)` still output is 2.

Why this is so.How it is working in background.

*Thnaks in advance!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Integer` objects are immutable objects and hence any change to them will create a new object. So when you change

```
i1 = 5;
```

the original `i1` which was stored in set is not changed. As i1 now holds the reference of a different object, which is not present in Set so calling

```
s.remove(i1);
```

will have no effect i.e. it does not remove anything and the size of the set remains 2. To confirm whether `remove` has removed anything or not, you can use boolean return value of `remove` method. It will return true if the value is removed. So try this:

```
if(s.remove(i1)) {
    System.out.println("i1 removed");
} else {
   System.out.println("i1 NOT removed");
}
```

Comment: Immutability is irrelevant. Exactly the same thing would have happened if the variables had been List references, as long as the final assignment to i1 was of a reference to an object that is not equal to any element in the set.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
i1 = 5;
```

is actually compiled to

```
i1 = Integer.valueOf(5);
```

So after execution, `i1` is holding another (new) reference, with a **value** that is not in the `HashSet`, so nothing is removed.

Comment: I know what you were trying to get at here, but ... it's a `HashSet`. `remove()` isn't looking at reference values ;)

Comment: @BrianRoach Ah, excuse the wording.

Comment: My point was the second bit; `i1 = 2; remove(i1)` would most certainly remove ithe `Integer` with the value `2` from the `HashSet`

Answer (score 2):

1. Java primitives types can only have **VALUES**.
2. While Java boxed types have **VALUE** and **IDENTITY**.
3. Two Java boxed types can have same **VALUE** but different **IDENTITY**.
4. Java boxed types are **IMMUTABLE**; any change in their **VALUE** will also change the **IDENTITY**.
5. If **IDENTITY** of an object is changed; Java collections cant work effectively.
6. Statement:  `i1 = 5;` => is actually `i1 = Integer.ValueOf(5)` => which meant new **VALUE** of `i1`.
7. Collections store only **IDENTITY** but not **VALUE**.
8. Removal by non existing **IDENTITY** `(i1 = 5)` from collection, will result nothing.

Source ..... Effective Java by Joshua Bloch

Answer (score 1):

Collections (Set is a collection) in java works with the 'equals()' method, not with the '=' reference operator.  That is, when you set 'i1=5', and then 's.remove(i1)', the  remove method will compare with all elements.

a) Beginning with the first:  is 5 equal to 1?.  No, so don't remove that element.

b) The second: is 5 equal to 2?.  No, so don't remove that element.

Adding duplicate works the same, on an empty set:

```
i1=1;
i2=1;
s.add(i1);
s.add(i2)
```

This will result on a set with only 1 element, because 'i1.equals(i2)' is true, and doesn't matter that 'i1=i2' is NOT true.

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to distinguish between objects and reference variables. A reference expression, including a reference variable, is either null or a pointer to some object.

The HashSet contains its own pointers to the objects in the set it represents. Working through the code:

```
Set<Integer> s = new HashSet();
// s is a pointer to a new, empty, HashSet.
Integer i1 = new Integer(1);
// i2 is a pointer to an Integer object with value 1
s.add(i1);
// The set contains one Integer object, value 1
Integer i2 = new Integer(2);
s.add(i2);
// The set contains two Integer objects, values 1 and 2
i1 = 5;
// i1 is a pointer to an Integer object with value 5
s.remove(i1);
// The set does not contain any object that is equal 
// to an Integer with value 5 so it is unchanged
```

Answer (score 0):

Becase after you do "i1 = 5;", i1 starts pointing to another address. And it is no more the same Integer than is stored in your HashSet.